# Get products by filters in magento android

Tags: magento-1.9, filter

HI is there any way to get the products with filters like filter by price, filter by brand names etc in  android? . I wanted to use "catalogProductList" magento api. Is that right one ? or I need to use any other api? If "catalogProductList" this one is the right api then how to send "filters" to this api? please let me know any reference is available for android.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try with filter parameter as below

```
“//Sample Code For Soap Client 
$client = new SoapClient(‘http://yourdomain.com/api/?wsdl’); 
// login     
try { 
    $session = $client->login(‘your_api_username’, ‘your_api_key’); 
    $filters = array( array(‘sku’ => array(‘like’=>’test%’),’name’=>array(‘eq’=>’Test’)) ); 
    $message=$client->call($session,’catalog.product.list’,$filters); print_r($message); 
} catch(Exception $fault) { 
  echo $fault->getMessage();
}”
```

hope this will worth for you.

Comment: Liyakat thanks, But I need it in android please let me know how to achieve this  one in android.

Comment: you may refer this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11682462/how-to-create-your-own-magento-mobile-application-for-android-and-iphone

Comment: I follwed this [link](http://wesleyli.blog.com/2013/09/27/android-call-magento-soap-v2-api-with-complex-filter/) . Its working great for "catalogProductList" api . But  to filter products with proice and brands which api i need to use?

Comment: liyakat could you please post the wsdl, api.xml file or any reference for creating configuration files for your code? Thanks in advance.

Comment: if my answer is little help to you.i would be happy if u accept it and vote up so some one can use in future.
you can refere this link http://inchoo.net/magento/magento-v2-soap-demystified/